# Java AES encryption weird result

Tags: encryption, aes

I'm trying to encrypt a simple string using AES algorithm.
Everything seems fine and i'm able to decrypt it.
Just for curiosity i printed the encrypted data to the console and i 
was surprised to see it.

Input String :   raw text string.

Encrypted data : Díå¼[¶cE¶Ÿ¸’E‚;èýaó1ÒŽ&ýÈZ

Decrypted Data : raw text string.

Can anyone explain me why the encrypted data bits are twice long as that of input string..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encryption works on blocks of data of a fixed size.  Appropriate padding is added during encoding and removed during decoding.

Comment: thanks for your reply, john. So it means that the remaining (128 - 16) bits are getting padded in this case ? (Since AES works on 128 bit block size)

Comment: Most (all?) encryption algorithms use a block size == key size. So AES with a 128 bit key uses 128 bit blocks.

Comment: yes but what i want to know is that the remaining bits get padded or not.if yes then by what ? Can i explicitly pad the remaining bits ?

Comment: They do. And you don't want to control that padding. It is done following a specific algorithm for security reasons. As a degenerate case, imagine you encrypted a single byte and padded with zeros. An attacker who knew this and read your encrypted ciphertext could use it as an "oracle". The attacker takes a guess at your key and confirms it by encrypting all 256 possible plaintext values, then comparing the encrypted ciphertext with yours.

Comment: so if the remaining bits are getting padded then why it doesn't reflects in the length of the encrypted data i'm getting ? I'm encrypting 16 length string and it gives me encrypted data of length 32 .. why not 128 since i'm using 128 bit key..?

Comment: You are confusing bits and bytes. You are encrypting a 16 character string that probably becomes 16 bytes plus a null terminator when encoded as bytes. So 17 bytes * 8 bits per byte = 136 bits to encrypt. That means two 128-bit blocks.

Comment: As @owlstead says below, if padding is used and the message fits exactly into blocks, the last block is always padding. So the thing I said about bytes and bits was correct, but I was probably wrong about the null terminator. You had 16 bytes of ciphertext + 16 bytes of padding.

Answer (score 0):

I would not rely on displaying a special character String to tell its length. On encryption, you typically get a `byte[]` for which `length` should give you the exact value. If you want it printed, a hex representation looks clearer:

```
public static void showHex(byte[] data) {
    final String HEXDIGITS = "0123456789abcdef";
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        int v = data[i] & 0xff;
        res.append(HEXDIGITS.charAt(v >> 4));
        res.append(HEXDIGITS.charAt(v & 0xf));
    }

    System.out.println(res);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, f_puras . I tried your code and came up with a different result. When i encrypt a 16 length string using aes , i get 32 bit length encrypted data and if i encrypt a 15 length string i get 16 bit encrypted data .. can you explain me why is this happening ?

Comment: As @johnwatts already mentioned, you have to take padding into account.

Comment: Puru, padding always happens, so a 16 byte plain text will get a full block of padding. This allows the unpadding mechanism to work regardless of the value of the end of the plaintext; the unpadding mechanism can distinguish between padding and plain text this way.